# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, identityserver4

We have create IdentityServer4 application with ASP.NET Core(http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html) and deployed it on our qa server(i.e. https://identityserver.mydomain.com). We have also created the AWS Server application in .NET Core(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/preview-of-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio-2017/) and this serverless application internally call the `connect/token` endpoint of identity server application.(i.e. https://identityserver.mydomain.com/connect/token).

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> CreateAccessToken(string baseUrl, string client, string clientSecret, string scope)
    {
        //discover endpoints from metadata
        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(baseUrl);
        //request token
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, client, clientSecret);
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(scope: scope);
        return tokenResponse;
    }
```

Everything is working on our localhost but after deploying the Serverless application on AWS we are getting following error:

```
    Unknown error responding to request: ArgumentNullException:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: address
at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient..ctor(String address, HttpMessageHandler innerHttpMessageHandler)
at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient..ctor(String address, String clientId, String clientSecret, HttpMessageHandler innerHttpMessageHandler, AuthenticationStyle style)
at F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.IdentityServer.Client.IdentityServerApiClient.<CreateAccessToken>d__0.MoveNext() in E:\Rakesh_Kumar\Online_TFS\MAP\API\Auth\_trunk\F2C.MAP.API\F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.IdentityServer.Client\IdentityServerApiClient.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.PublicAPI.Controllers.AuthorizeController.<Get>d__3.MoveNext() in E:\Rakesh_Kumar\Online_TFS\MAP\API\Auth\_trunk\F2C.MAP.API\F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.PublicAPI\Controllers\AuthorizeController.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.RequestScopingStartupFilter.<<ConfigureRequestScoping>b__3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<ProcessRequest>d__16.MoveNext()
ArgumentNullException:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: address
at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient..ctor(String address, HttpMessageHandler innerHttpMessageHandler)
at IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient..ctor(String address, String clientId, String clientSecret, HttpMessageHandler innerHttpMessageHandler, AuthenticationStyle style)
at F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.IdentityServer.Client.IdentityServerApiClient.<CreateAccessToken>d__0.MoveNext() in E:\Rakesh_Kumar\Online_TFS\MAP\API\Auth\_trunk\F2C.MAP.API\F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.IdentityServer.Client\IdentityServerApiClient.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.PublicAPI.Controllers.AuthorizeController.<Get>d__3.MoveNext() in E:\Rakesh_Kumar\Online_TFS\MAP\API\Auth\_trunk\F2C.MAP.API\F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.PublicAPI\Controllers\AuthorizeController.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.RequestScopingStartupFilter.<<ConfigureRequestScoping>b__3_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<ProcessRequest>d__16.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Set a log message just before `var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, client, clientSecret);` and check the parameters that you are sending. The error says that `disco.TokenEndpoint` is null. Check why is that

Comment: when i set log, i found disco variable null, but its working fine at localhost, couldn't why its not initialized after deploying on aws environment.